# Why did my Ubuntu shutdown?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Last night my Ubuntu box turned itself off.

Thus morning I turned it back on (after blowing out a couple of year's dust and dog hair) then checked syslog. There was nothing - a message where my nightly backup mounted the drive I do backups to then nothing until I powered it on this morning.

It didn't lose power - my cable modem is plugged into the same power strip, and it would have still been initializing when I checked, and it wasn't.

My guesses are either that the power supply is getting flaky, or that it overheated (which is why I blew out the dust.)

The question is - if there anyplace I could look that might provide information about why it went down other than syslog?

Comment: I checked only a couple of seconds after the shutdown. The fans has been running loud enough that I noticed their not running.

Comment: So what were you doing before it shutdown? Were you actively working on the system? Why did you decide you would clean it before turning it on again?

Answer (score 1):

A power failure is still a possible explanation. A short enough power failure can affect some devices and not others. Additionally power failures can take out just one of the three phases. So if those devices are on different phases it is even more likely that a power failure took out just one.

There is a couple of things you can look for in the log files which will hint of an unclean shutdown. NUL characters due to logs not flushed before power was lost and a journal replay or file system check at boot.

None of these will tell you exactly why the system was not shut down cleanly. And it should be sort of obvious that Ubuntu cannot write that information to the log when it is no longer running. It is possible that the BIOS may know at next boot if it was triggered by power failure, power button, reset button, system crash, or OS deliberately rebooting.

Mots BIOS have a setting which decides if the system will power on when power is restored. If the actual behavior you have observed is inconsistent with that setting it may indicate the machine was powered down for a different reason.

Comment: "Additionally power failures can take out just one of the three phases.": If this person is using a power strip, chances are there is only one phase presented on the power strip.  That is unless the computer is in a datacenter with dogs (per the dog hair in the power supply), and it is a pretty fancy power strip (usually called a PDU, and I don't think I've ever used a multi-phase PDU)

Comment: The machine is configured to reboot on power restore, and it didn't. Which makes me think that it was a hardware-triggered shutdown. Which still has me thinking it was overheating. (The fan screens were pretty much blocked.)

Comment: @Slartibartfast Good point. I missed the part about same power strip. Power strips with multiple phases are indeed rare. Power failures short enough to allow some equipment to keep running unaffected are not so rare.

Comment: @jdege I have seen some Linux system that output messages about thermal sensors in the kernel log. But I don't have much detail as I usually don't deal with overheating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking to see if you have auditing enabled.  This would be in the form of the log messages in `/var/log/audit/` and the `ausearch` tool.

If enabled, the audit logs tend to be a little more verbose than syslog (they record things like file accesses and process starts/stops), so at  least you should have better resolution as to the time of the power loss.  They will also likely have events that you could (with significant effort) associate with the various ways the computer might shut down.

There is also the command `last`, but based on the info you've shared you are unlikely to see useful info there.

Answer (score 0):

A hard power off is hardware. If it just shut off with no shutdown routine, based on what you said about the fans, sounds like it overheated.

Comment: Temps are fine, today. And the fans are quieter.

Comment: Is it a laptop? I have to open mine once a year or so and blow out the fans cause I have cats.